# How Spring Scrypt PasswordEncoder knows the original salt to be able to verify the password

Tags: spring-security, hash, scrypt

Hashing "`MYpassword`" using **SCrypt** in Spring twice generate two different hashes which is the expected result since the salt is different.

```
hash 1: $100801$DBrs3RHYQafAjmY0RGGgtA==$VB1ahwEHntb36HWbAF1Eiy6FoJp1WH8xmpYY4+oHPUk=
hash 2: $100801$0EEqkaQUDzVCttua+jqu9A==$tstqjgsW5bzWXwRZKIeVy9P3jh/92QrZ8SW+8iLl7dc=
```

What I don't understand is that to verify the password, Scrypt needs the original salt used to hash. After searching, I found out it gets the salt from the hash field itself. So where is it exactly in the above examples? I searched for scrypt format decoded and nothing came up.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4a50d5aab38de67cbc470d6e02bb5d18ec8dfd3c/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/scrypt/SCryptPasswordEncoder.java#L194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/scrypt/SCryptPasswordEncoder.java),

```
private String digest(CharSequence rawPassword, byte[] salt) {
    byte[] derived = SCrypt.generate(Utf8.encode(rawPassword), salt, this.cpuCost, this.memoryCost,
            this.parallelization, this.keyLength);
    String params = Long.toString(
            ((int) (Math.log(this.cpuCost) / Math.log(2)) << 16L) | this.memoryCost << 8 | this.parallelization,
            16);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((salt.length + derived.length) * 2);
    sb.append("$").append(params).append('$');
    sb.append(encodePart(salt)).append('$');
    sb.append(encodePart(derived));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The parameter, salt, and hash are appended next to each other with `$` separator, so the middle value is the encoded salt.